# Drupal 7: Get all enabled fields for given node type?

Tags: drupal

Is there an easy way to do this using Drupal API? I tried `node_type_get_type($type)`but it returns only basic info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try using `field_info_instances` it basically returns all fields information

Example usage

```
field_info_instances('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, it's

```
$fields = field_info_instances("node", "your_node_type");
```